Popup Error's in IDE when not running, vb.net VS2022
I have a complex solution with 27 projects in it. It is a tabbed interface with user controls. Trying to open up the main form causes many errors at times with no stack trace available. But, I do get object not set to an object at times in a pop up error message from the IDE. It is a generic error so I can't trace it.
Most of the user controls are inherited objects at runtime or reference collections that are created from the app.config(s) file at runtime.
The issue is how do I stop the IDE from either running code within itself when it's not actually running or stop the error pop ups from happening.
Where I can I have put "If DesignMode Then Exit Sub" but that doesn't completely fix it. Any idea's on where to go from here?
Thanks
Where I can I have put "If DesignMode Then Exit Sub" but that doesn't completely fix it.

look at the error warnig list and eliminate firt every error and then clean up the rest

Yes, but why the pop up errors in the IDE? can't that be stopped?

that is hard to tell without a [mre] but try my approach and the problem will goaway

I suspect that the message-boxes are Visual Studio's behaviour and there is no alternative way to display those error messages / to disable the message-boxes. If you focus on the message-box content, you might be able to find suggestions on resolving the errors.

The IDE itself runs the code. I have gotten error messages that I have added for things like no records found. Even thought I am checking for being in DesignMode.

Have you manually modified the code in your designer file? When you try to open a form, it loads the form from the designer file, which can cause an error.
You'll need to resolve these errors to open the form correctly.
Also try using Conditional Compilation.
#If DESIGN_MODE Then
    ' Code that runs only during design mode
#Else
    ' Code that runs during runtime
#End If


I have fixed errors in the designer that caused the form from loading. Or fixed errors after the form loaded and blew out pieces of it. But no intentional mods.

DesignMode in user controls sometimes can be tricky. Make sure you check DesignMode at the control's constructor or Load event.

Yes, in the load event. Some classes can't use DesignMode however and I think they are the offending ones. Still trying to get that fixed. Thanks.

Try using Conditional Compilation in Code. Check the code in my edited answer.

It seems that there is no one cure for checking for design mode. I have tried using the DesignMode boolean as well as the license manager checks -
If LicenseManager.UsageMode = LicenseUsageMode.Designtime Then Exit Sub But neither works in every instance. I have to use these both for the message box's them selves and that stopped the popups. I was hoping to stop the complete sub/function execution but that doesn't seem to work.
Thanks to all for the idea's.
